# Hyperplane cut Euclidean space, at most how many subspaces we can get

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry

Suppose there is a $p$ dimensional Euclidean space. If we use $m$ $p-1$ dimensional   hyperplane to cut this Euclidean space, at most how many subspaces we can get?

Comment: The result should be related to both $p$ and $m$ and may need discussion among different relations between  $p$ and $m$.

Comment: I suggest you start with $p=2$, see what answer you find there first.

Comment: I found it should be $n(n+1)/2 + 1$ when $p=2$, but not that easy to extend to higer $p$.